# Is it possible to log POST data size in nginx?

Tags: logging, file-upload, nginx, webserver, image-uploading

To be specific, I want to log the size of image uploaded to my server in `Nginx`.

Currently this is what I have :

`log_format main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                     '"$http_host" $request_time';`

Probably it may not be possible to have the size of the image data alone, but I am fine with logging size of the whole `POST`data

Comment: Have you tried "$content_length" or "$request_length" ?

Comment: I haven't, but I will try that.